# Minimising function names with lengthy parameters

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

We are using a web service to fetch data. As project progressed, number of params being passed between functions also increased. To make it more readable and easier to add/remove parameters in future thought of using a dictionary instead. So every function calls will have only one parameter , a dictionary with all required parameters in it.

So to set a parameter I need to do `[aDictionary setObject:foo forkey:@"bar"]` and to get a parameter, it would be `[aDictionary objectForKey:@"bar"]`.

To access the variables easily I thought of using a Model class with all common parameters used as properties. So for one function call say 3 out of 10 properties would be used and rest will be not be set. So it would be like `paramModel.foo = @"bar"`.

If I would do it like this, will I be wasting memory for unused properties which are not initialised. And is this right in doing so ?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing Amin Negm-Awad's points: If you are finding yourself passing along a lot of parameters to many methods, you almost certainly have incorrectly defined your model classes. Rather than creating a generic dictionary, create a simple value object that holds the related properties.

As an example, consider `NSURL`. You would never do this:

```
[self handleScheme:scheme host:host path:path];
```

Instead you do this:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:scheme host:host path:path];
[self handleURL:URL];
```

This is the correct way to consolidate parameters, and to improve your design.

Also, if you're taking a large number of boolean parameters or other kinds of "options," first consider whether you have a method that is doing too many things. Perhaps it should just be broken up into multiple methods that each works a specific way. If you really do need to pass multiple boolean options, in ObjC, this is often done with bit fields rather than with many parameters. Look at `[NSString rangeOfString:options:]` for an example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is strange. (Of course this is a subjective opinion.)

A. "As project progressed, number of params being passed between functions also increased."

There is only a connection between size of a software and numbers of parameters to a method (in your example there is no function): if you do something wrong in your design.

Split your code into modules, into classes, define good relationships between them and so on. 
Define classes that can hold connected data.

B. I cannot see, what becomes more readable using dictionaries:

```
[receiver doSomethingWithA:@"a"
                         B:@"b"
                         C:@"c"];

NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[aDictionary setObject:@"a" forKey:@"A"];
[aDictionary setObject:@"b" forKey:@"B"];
[aDictionary setObject:@"c" forKey:@"C"];
[receiver doSomethingWithABC:aDictionary];
```

It is more code, it is more complex code (because it needs an additional instance object), arguments and its "parameter destination" are wrested apart.

Inside the method you have to read out the arguments from the dictionary. This is additional boiler plate code.

Comment: I wanted to do something like option B. As you mentioned its not readable, to avoid that I thought of using another class which would hold all the params. I need to minimise calls because some functions take up 6~10 parameters.

Comment: another class would still be more complicate than the usual usage in the first statement.